Replace blank with value in dax formula
how can I replace the blank values with the "19000101" int value in this dax formula.
Is Active During Selected Date:=
IF (
    VALUE ( FORMAT ( MAX ( 'Creator'[Date Account Disabled] ), "YYYYMMDD" ) )
        > MIN ( 'Date'[PK_Date] ),
    1,
    0
)

my error is this

Calculation error in measure 'Creator'[Is Active During
Selected Date]: Cannot convert value '' of type Text to type Number.

after checking the data, [Date Account Disabled] has some blank values in the relationship with the Fact table.

your DAX is not correct. format returns the string. why you use value(format)?  Pls provide some sample data and expected output
